# How to get all your facebook status and count how many users liked it

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to get all of my status in facebook at the same time I want to count how many people liked it. Is that possible using the Facebook API?

Your guidance or help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by calling `/me/feed` to get a user's status updates. Each update will have a `id`. You will then need to make a second API call to `/[id]/likes` to get a list of user's who have liked that update.